# How to send Date field of JSON object to the struts2 Action

Tags: json, rest, struts2

I am using struts **interceptor-ref name="json** and sending a request from postman to the action class which are configured in struts.xml. When i sent a request it is able to capture all the parameters which sent from postman request except Date fields.

Action class

```
public class RestAction extends ActionSupport implements Action {
    private int tenure;
    private  String tenureType;
    private Date fromDate;
    private Date toDate;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Request

```
{
    "fromDate":"2014-01-01T13:13:34.441Z",
    "toDate":"2014-01-01T23:28:56.782Z",
    "tenure":"60"
    "tenureType":"week"         
}
```

is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Date fields setter method parameter type is String instead of Date

Previous

```
public Date getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }

    public void setFromDate(String fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }

    public Date getToDate() {
        return toDate;
    }

    public void setToDate(String toDate) {
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }
```

After

```
public Date getFromDate() {
        return fromDate;
    }

    public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
    }

    public Date getToDate() {
        return toDate;
    }

    public void setToDate(Date toDate) {
        this.toDate = toDate;
    }
```

Due to that it is not calling setter methods of date fields.